# JMeter: do not measure the connection establishment by the first call

Tags: jmeter

I want to automatically test a Web API service, but the measurement is not correct because of the connection establishment, it takes a long time, and I want to run just a short test.

Is it possible to make a first sampler, just because of that and not include it's result into the summary?

Comment: I am a noob with JMeter, I have  just created a sampler with pre and postprocessor, with some variables and JSON postprocessor. Until now I used it just for web site test and profiling (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/test-profile.html)

Comment: Are you using JMeter in Non-GUI mode? share your script details. It is not clear from your question that what are you going to measure and which components are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I can not. There is a .Net Web API service, and I want test it with a http request sampler, but after an IIS reset the connection establishment is already measureable. And yes, I use it in non-GUI mode, but I think it does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different name for the First request you want to emit and exclude it from the results (report).

You can do it in a [setup Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) using 1 threads, this way it will run at the start of your test and then the real test can start.